Git Fetch command not fetching latest changes from Azure DevOps repo
I'm trying to fetch the latest changes from origin/main to local main. The output window shows:

Fetching from MyRepo


git: 'credential-manager-core' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

I then changed 'credential-manager-core' to 'credential-manager' in the gitconfig file and tried again. Then I get:

Fetching from MyRepo

And the latest updates don't get fetched and my local main stays the same.
What is wrong?

According to your description, assuming you are using the Fetch Option in the Git Menu of Visual Studio 2022.

In my test, if there are some updates on the origin/main, it will show this in the output window when using the fetch option.
Fetching from MyRepo
Remote: Azure Repos        
Remote: 
Remote: Found 3 objects to send. (0 ms)        
From https://dev.azure.com/organization/project/_git/MyRepo
   f3f4e7f..835f0a0  main       -> origin/main

After the above action, if I click the fetch option again, it only shows
Fetching from MyRepo

We can open the Branches page by clicking the Git ->Manage Branches.
Then select the main branch and check the commits which is fetched from the origin/main in the incoming session.

After confirming the code is correct, use the Pull option to update the local branch with the commits which is fetched from the origin/main.
The output window:
Updating f3f4e7f..835f0a0

Now, the local main branch is up to date.
If in the Branches page, you still cannot see any update in the incoming session and cannot do a git pull action, please try the following steps:

Install the latest Git version from the Git download page.
Install the latest Git Credential Manager. See the installation instructions for the current version of GCM for install options for your operating system.

